# Create custom admin page with custom text fields

Tags: php, customization

I want to create a custom admin page which contains 3 text-fields. These text fields should have a default text in them. But the admin should be able to edit this and save the customized text. Which should save to the database and be able to be picked up in the front end.
I was thinking about doing a custom post type for this. But in custom post types you are able to create multiple posts. And I just want 3 text fields, and 3 database values for this.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?
Could not find anything when I searched.

Comment: Depends on your definition of simple. If the fields should show up on the front-end, then it sounds like the Customiser would be the right place to put them, in which case you'd use the [Customize API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/), or if you want them in a page under Settings, you'd use the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/).

Comment: The fields should not show up on the front-end, I just want to be able to use the text from the fields on the front-end. And I would like to create a custom admin page, not integrate in the Settings. Is this possible?

Comment: That's what I mean by showing up on the front end.

Comment: I understand, but the Customizer is not the way to go for this. As this page is not reachable when in Customizer. It is not linked to on the main page.

Comment: Of course it's reachable. Go to the page and click Customize in the admin bar.

Comment: I have the admin bar hidden throughout the site. Is it possible to create a Customizer menu item which on click loads the specific page, and when you exit the menu, goes back to the start page?

Comment: please check link:https://jacobmartella.com/2018/01/17/add-wordpress-admin-page-data-custom-table/